# Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")

Tags: python

So, I use thonny to code python. And I keep getting this error. (Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
If someone can help me it will be greatly appreciated. Happy Chirtmas!

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
print(numbers)
index = 0
for i in numbers:
    print(numbers[index] + 19)
    index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your list contains numbers as strings:
It should be like this:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(numbers)
index = 0
for i in numbers:
    print(numbers[index] + 19)
    index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
print(numbers)
index = 0
for i in numbers:
  print(int(numbers[index]) + 19)
  index = index + 1
```

You are trying to add string to integer. Do Typecasting from string to integer

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add together integer and string. That isn't going to work. If they are integers, you should store them in your list without quotes.

`numbers = [1,2,3]`

You should also simplify your `for` loop.

```
for i in numbers:
    print(i + 19)
```

Python iterates over content of the list automatically, so `i` will automatically become every element of the list without having to do anything extra, thus incrementing the index (or accessing the list using index) is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
print(numbers)
for i in numbers:
    print(int(i) + 19)
```

You are adding str to an integer that's why you are getting the error.
Yo do not need index also as you are looping through the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains strings and not numbers and thus cannot be added to eachother.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # note the lack of quotes
result = [i + 19 for i in numbers]
```